# batch file: search file system for specific folders and execute a command for every hit

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

I am new to batch files and need some help. I want to do the following.

I created a batch file that is looking for the folder "Recordings" within the file system and writes the results to a text file (results.txt).
After that it is looking for the string "Directory" within the results.
I want then merge every line from findstr (every path) with the execution-command of a tool I am using.

batchfile.bat:

```
@echo off
dir /S Recordings > C:\testing\results.txt
findstr Directory C:\testing\results.txt
PAUSE
```

The output looks like this:

```
C:\testing>batchfile.bat
 Directory of C:\testing\Scenarios\Default
 Directory of C:\testing\Scenarios\test1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Now I want every line of this output to be merged with my execution-command:

```
tool.exe -parameter C:\testing\Scenarios\Default\Recordings
tool.exe -parameter C:\testing\Scenarios\test1\Recordings
```

Answer (score 1):

#### I want every line of this output to be merged with my execution-command

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`dir /a:d /b /s ^| findstr "Recordings"`) do (
  tool.exe -parameter %%i
  )
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.

Comment: @Jimi Great. Do you need more help? If this answered your question, please don't forget to [accept the answer](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the accept button (the tick ✓ button).